# 1. if a * 133 – m * 277 = 1, does this guarantee that a has an inverse mod m? If so, what is it? If not, why not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

The problem im tasked with is

if $$a * 133 – m * 277 = 1$$, does this guarantee that a has an inverse mod m? If so, what is it? If not, why not?

I know the answer is 133 mod m, but im not sure how to get from the question to the answer. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your posts. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It might be helpful to know what it means for $a$ to have an inverse mod $m$.

Comment: $a$ has an inverse mod $m$ if there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax 
 - 1 = my$. Now, do you see why the above implies $a$ has an inverse $\mod m$?

Comment: Well, $25 \cdot 133 - 12 \cdot 277 = 1.$ What are $a,m,$ and does $a$ have an inverse $\pmod m \; ?$